# Python exception handling, corner case scenario failing

Tags: python, exception

I am learning python exception handling. I came across a challenge where I had to define a function to raise exceptions when certain conditions didn't meet. I was able to raise exceptions just fine for all the hidden test cases but one. Here's my code below:

```
def Handle_Exc1():
try:
    
    a=int(input())
    b=int(input())   
    if not (a<150 and b>100):
        raise ValueError('Input integers value out of range.')
except ValueError as e:
      print(e)  

else:
    try:
        c=a+b
        if c>400:
            raise ValueError('Their sum is out of range')
    except ValueError as f:
            print(f)
    else:
        print("All in range")
```

The above code worked for all the hidden test cases but one. I cannot find out what kind of scenario or whats the input is given either. However, the code should have been able to handle all the scenarios. But it isn't. Need your help to figure out how I could have made this code foolproof.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Mahi

Comment: What error is showing?

Comment: What was the spec?  We can't possibly guess that, and without it, we can't diagnose anything.

Comment: Are you supposed to CATCH the errors, or are you just supposed to RAISE the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. I missed to include values 150 and 100 in the if statement. Working code below:

```
def Handle_Exc1():
try:
    
    a=int(input())
    b=int(input())   
    if not (a<=150 and b>=100):
        raise ValueError('Input integers value out of range.')  


    c=a+b
    if c>400:
        raise ValueError('Their sum is out of range')

except ValueError as f:
    print(f)
else:
    print("All in range")
```

This passed all the test cases.

Comment: My code is also same as yours. But still two hidden cases fail Any idea where I am going wrong.

Comment: a = int(input())
    b = int(input())
    sums = a + b
    
    
    if (a > 150) or (b < 100):
        raise ValueError('Input integers value out of range.')
    elif sums > 400:
        raise ValueError('Their sum is out of range')
    else:
        print('All in range.')

Comment: Compare your code to my working code with each line. You might figure out what are you missing. I believe you have raised the first error after the sum. which should have been before summing.

Comment: .thanks for the input , but I had extra dot in "All in range." and I was going haywire over logic. I removed the dot and my test cases passed. Dig mountain and mouse came out like comedy with me :)

Answer (score 0):

can you tell that one hidden test scenario which is failing & what input is given you can pass the variable in error, you don't have to create `try` and `except` block every time you just allow in outer scope

```
try:
    
    a=int(input('a:'))
    b=int(input('b:'))   

    if a>=150 :
        raise ValueError('Input integer a  value out of range. it should be less than 150,you provide :',a)
    elif b<= 100:
        raise ValueError('Input integer b  value out of range. it should be greater than 100,you provide :',b)

    c = a+b

    if c>400:
        raise ValueError('Their sum is greater than 400. sum is :',c)

except ValueError as f:
        print(f)
```

Comment: Its a hidden test case. Out of 10 cases 9 are passing and one is failing. I guess this is a corner case scenario which I am not able to figure out so far. If I were to write a brute-force test for this how can I do that?

Comment: I missed to add  (a<=150 and b>=100) in the first if statement. That was the hidden test case.